# Pulleys, Torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Consider a pulley with two masses hung by an unstretchable rope. Is torque only introduced when the string is not massless and the pulley has friction (do we care if the pulley is frictionless or not, or is the mass of the rope the main concern)?

Comment: Friction would be necessary to turn the pulley as that causes tension to change, think about a friction-less yo yo, the string would just slide out without turning the spool. Mass isn't necessary, the friction can also be generated by the Normal pressure from tension, too.

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. Are the masses equal? Is the length of rope on both sides equal? What is your difficulty?

Comment: Both masses are not equal. This question is from an intro newtonian mechanics university course.

Answer (score 1):

The mass of the string is of no concern as Rick points out the friction can also be generated by the normal pressure from tension, too.

If pulley is mass-less, there will be no rotation(i.e. no torque) for it with or without friction and the tension on both sides will be equal.

If the pulley has mass, but is friction-less, there will be no rotation(i.e. no torque) and the tension on both sides will again be equal.

If the pulley has mass and friction there will be rotation and different tension on both sides.